# Google Maps centering fails at smaller viewport size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Using the following barebones code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map_area" style="width:100%;padding-bottom:100%;"></div>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCfoIZz72NPrAPegHrWxqZtvzGkTASDXMc&sensor=false'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng(38.504806, -122.470542);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: center,
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_area"),  mapOptions);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Example available at http://test.wcwddemo.com.

At larger (e.g. desktop) viewport sizes, it works as expected, centering a map on the small California town of St. Helena.

If you shrink the size of the viewport and refresh the screen, at some point (around a width of 625px), the map is no longer centered on the town. Instead, the town seems to be centered on the lower boundary of the map container.

On the surface, this appears to be a bug. Am I missing something? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a height-style for map_area.

From the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Map_DOM_Elements): *you must always set a size on that `<div>` explicitly*

Comment: 1. If that were the problem, the larger viewport sizes would presumably show the same issue.
2. I added height:100% to the example, and the symptoms are the same.

Comment: did you notice the right scrollbar appearing with height:100% ? The map is centered now at the desired location, but the map is larger than the browsers viewport. Scroll the page to  center the map within the browsers viewport, and  you'll see that the map is centered at St. Helena

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to. I took a screenshot immediately after a refresh and put it at http://test.wcwddemo.com/screenshot.jpg. There is no scrollbar, and what should be the center is at the bottom under the copyright notice.

Comment: That's what I see: http://i.imgur.com/IH2BE.jpg Inspect #map_area with the chrome-developer-tools, and you will see that the computed style for height is 0px, that's the problem here. When you set the height to a percentage value, the parent element must have a height set too, otherwise the browser is not able to calculate the height(100% of what??). Solution: `body,html{height:100%;}`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I want to keep the aspect ratio of the map canvas constant, so your suggested CSS does not accomplish what I need. But I wrapped the map div in a container, set the container to maintain it's aspect ratio, and set the height and width of the map canvas to match the container. That seems to solve the problem.